# CLion Full Remote Mode with FreeBSD as the remote host

Tags: c++, c, remote-debugging, freebsd, clion

Currently, the [Full Remote Mode](https://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2018/09/initial-remote-dev-support-clion/) of CLion only supports Linux as a remote host OS. Is it possible to have a FreeBSD remote host?

Comment: Obligatory [It’s OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can!

However, note that I'm recalling these steps retrospectively, so probably I have missed one step or two. Should you encounter any problem, please feel free to leave a comment below.

1. Rent a FreeBSD server, of course :)
2. Update your system to the latest release. Otherwise, you may get weird errors like `"libdl.so.1" not found` when installing packages. The one I'm using is FreeBSD 12.0-RELEASE-p3.
3. Create a user account. Don't forget to make it a member of `wheel`, and uncomment the `%wheel ALL=(ALL) ALL` line in `/usr/local/etc/sudoers`.
4. Set up SSH. This step is especially tricky, because we need to use both public-key and password authentication.

   1. Due to a [known bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-14580), in some cases, the remote host must use password authentication, or you'll get an error when setting up the toolchain. You can enable password authentication by setting `PasswordAuthentication yes` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, followed by a `sudo /etc/rc.d/sshd restart`.
   2. It appears that CLion synchronizes files between the local and remote host with `rsync` and SSH. For some reasons I cannot explain, this process will hang forever if the host server doesn't support passphrase-less SSH key login. Follow [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/241593/431150) to create an SSH key as an additional way of authentication.
5. CLion assumes the remote host OS to be Linux, so we must fix some incompatibilities between GNU/Linux and FreeBSD.

   1. Install GNU utilities with `sudo pkg install coreutils`.
   2. Rename the BSD utility `stat` with `sudo mv /usr/bin/stat /usr/bin/_stat`.
   3. Create a "new" file `/usr/bin/stat` with the content in **Snippet 1**. This hack exploits the fact that CLion sets the environment variable `JETBRAINS_REMOTE_RUN` to `1` before running commands on the remote server.
   4. Do `sudo chmod a+x /usr/bin/stat` to make it executable.
   5. Again, rename the BSD utility `ls` with `sudo mv /bin/ls /bin/_ls`.
   6. Create a "new" file `/bin/ls` with the content in **Snippet 2**, like before.
   7. Lastly, `sudo chmod a+x /bin/ls`.
6. Install the dependencies with `sudo pkg install rsync cmake gcc gdb gmake`.
7. Now you can follow the [official instructions](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/remote-projects-support.html), and connect to your shiny FreeBSD host!

[image]

---

**Snippet 1**

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ -z "$JETBRAINS_REMOTE_RUN" ]
then
        exec "/usr/bin/_stat" "$@"
else
        exec "/usr/local/bin/gnustat" "$@"
fi
```

**Snippet 2**

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ -z "$JETBRAINS_REMOTE_RUN" ]
then
        exec "/bin/_ls" "$@"
else
        exec "/usr/local/bin/gls" "$@"
fi
```

Comment: Starting 2020.1 version CLion uses jsch-nio with proper fix as result it works correctly with bsd `stat` and `ls` commands.

Answer (score 1):

Additionally you need to fix one more incompatibility between GNU/Linux and FreeBSD.

1. Check `gtar` is installed if no `pkg install gtar`
2. Rename the BSD utility `tar` with `mv /usr/bin/tar /usr/bin/_tar`
3. Create a "new" file `/usr/bin/tar` with the content in Snippet 3, like before.
4. Lastly, `sudo chmod a+x /usr/bin/tar`

**Snippet 3**

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ -z "$JETBRAINS_REMOTE_RUN" ]
then
        exec "/usr/bin/_tar" "$@"
else
        exec "/usr/local/bin/gtar" "$@"
fi
```

Comment: Starting CLion 2020.2 it's not required.

Answer (score 1):

1. Starting CLion 2020.1 the instruction regarding **gnustat** and "ls" is not relevant anymore. Because CLion 2020.1 includes the proper fixes in **jsch-nio** library (https://github.com/lucastheisen/jsch-nio/commit/410cf5cbb489114b5da38c7c05237f6417b9125b)
2. Starting CLion 2020.2 doesn't use tar `--dereference` option, so the instruction regarding **gtar** (gnutar) is also not relevant anymore.